# How to convert a list into object with multiple parameters

Tags: python, list, object

so I have an object called element and i have a csv file which has 118 lines of information regarding an element i.e atomic number, name, symbol, etc. so for the object it has 8 parameters and the Csv file is ordered in a way where each parameter is matched with the column so i want each line of the csv file to equal one element

```
from instream import InStream 
from outstream import OutStream 
import stdarray 
from element import Element


InStream('periodic_table.csv') 

instream = InStream('periodic_table.csv')
i = 0
while instream.hasNextLine():
    i += 1
    row = (instream.readLine())
    data = (row.split(',')) 
    column = len(data)

out = stdarray.create1D(i) 

InStream('periodic_table.csv') 

instream = InStream('periodic_table.csv')
instream.readLine()
i = 0
while instream.hasNextLine():
    i += 1
    row = (instream.readLine())
    data = (row.split(','))

    out[i] = Element(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7])
```

he last part is what I tried I was looking for a more efficient way to go about this

Comment: What is particularly inefficient about this?

Comment: What is `InStream`? Why aren't you using a regular `file` object, and possibly `csv.reader()`?

Comment: Why does your Python look like Java? Is this Jython?

Comment: @AlexHall Found it in google: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/instream.py.html Seems unnecessary for this.

Comment: What's `stdarray`?

Answer (score 2):

```
out[i] = Element(*data)
```

or if `data` might have more elements, take a slice:

```
out[i] = Element(*data[:8])
```

Better yet, use a `csv.DictReader`, make the CSV column names match the `Element` parameter names, and `data` can be a dict of keyword arguments:

```
out[i] = Element(**data)
```

Then you don't have to worry about order and you will get informative error messages if something goes wrong.